# React state gets updated only after I submit the form twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

State [txnId] gets updated when I submit the form twice. I want state to update right away when I submit the form and pass that prop using history.push to another component.

```
  const Cert = (props) => {
  const [vmobile, setVmobile] = useState("");
  const [txnId, setTxnId] = useState("");


  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https://api",
        {
          mobile: vmobile,
        }
      );

      setTxnId(data.txnId);

      if (txnId) {
          props.history.push({
          pathname: "/authorise",
          state: { txnId: txnId },
        });
      
    }
```

Comment: state is updated asynchronously and it is constant within a particular render of a component. So using the state value right _after_ calling the state setter function will give you the old state. Component has to re-render before it can see the updated state. You can use `if (data.txnId)` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't pass `txnId` to `props.history.push` just after call `setTxnId`. This because `setTxnId` is async. Use `data.txnId` instead. So your code becomes:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    "https://api",
    {
      mobile: vmobile,
    }
  );

  setTxnId(data.txnId);

  if (data.txnId) {  // <-- here use data.txnId instead of txnId 
      props.history.push({
      pathname: "/authorise",
      state: { txnId: data.txnId }, // <-- here pass data.txnId instead of txnId 
    });
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `txnId` just updated, you should use `useEffect` hook in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (txnId) {
      props.history.push({
      pathname: "/authorise",
      state: { txnId: txnId }, 
    });
  }
}, [txnId]);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https://api",
        {
          mobile: vmobile,
        }
      );

      setTxnId(data.txnId);
}
```

Comment: Now it's working..thanks for the clarity about async ...

Comment: @user2809967 it's a pleasure. Have a nice coding =)